# specializing for "direct" function types (as opposed to function-pointer types)

Tags: c++, templates, syntax, function-pointers

There's a difference between function types and function *pointer* types (for historic reasons AFAIK), the former automatically converting into the latter in some circumstances.

```
typedef void (TFoo)(); // a function type
typedef void (*TBar)(); // a function POINTER type
```

---

It's possible to use a template to deduce a function pointer's return type and parameter types. Eg:

```
template <typename T>
struct SFunctionInfo;

template <typename R, typename ... P>
struct SFunctionInfo<R (*)(P ...)>
  {
    using TReturn = R;

    // You could also store the params in a custom type like:
    // using TParams = SSomeVariadicTemplateStruct<P ...>;
  };

template <typename T>
using TFunctionReturn = typename SFunctionInfo<T>::TReturn;

// ...

using TBarReturn = TFunctionReturn<TBar>;
```

Q1: Is the same possible for non-pointer function types? I can't figure out the syntax. Trying:

```
template <typename T>
struct SFunctionInfo;

template <typename R, typename ... P>
struct SFunctionInfo<R ()(P ...)>
  { /* ... */ };
```

Fails (via g++):

```
error: ‘type name’ declared as function returning a function
```

Although you can use `R (&)(P ...)` (and `&&`) to match function *reference* types.

And `typedef` doesn't work with templates.

---

Q2 (related, may solve Q1): Is there a syntax to allow alias declarations of template non-pointer function types, similar to:

```
template <typename R, typename ... P>
using TFunction = R (*)(P ...);
```

---

Q3 (related, may solve Q1): Is it possible to convert function-pointer types to function types (and vice versa) without resorting to detecting the return & parameters and reconstructing said types?

Comment: Motivation? I was wondering whether it would be cleaner to (RTTI) inspect function types, then cast function-pointers to those types for inspection. But it's mostly academic, as "direct" function types seem almost unofficially deprecated so it's probably better to explicitly reject them.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't match the error message, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Your second question answers itself and use `std::remove_pointer` for removing pointers.

Comment: @PasserBy: If put the 3 blocks together it does, but I'll fix the Q1 block so it generates it by itself.

Comment: remove_pointer works, (and so does the usual remove-pointer by specialization trick). I messed up and tried it a wierd way and it didn't (due to dereferencing doing nothing). Apologies.

Comment: Solved the 1st question too (just don't use any initial bracket), will write an answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

**Q2**:

```
template <typename R, typename ... P>
using TFunction = R(P ...);
```

**Q1**:

Use the syntax from Q2:

```
template <typename R, typename ... P>
struct SFunctionInfo<R(P...)>
  {};
```

**Q3**:

There's no need to do anything different than for regular pointer referencing/dereferencing. (I just messed up testing it).

- function-type -> function-pointer-type: just add *
- function-pointer-type -> function-type: specialize a struct for T* (or just use std::remove_pointer, as PasserBy said above)

Comment: This question is trivial, sorry. It wasn't well tested because I overcomplicated my testing and just confused myself, twice.